# Reading Catalyst 4500X / 2960 / etc. configuration

Tags: switch, cisco-catalyst

this could be a really stupid question but i haven't found any solution on the internet. One of our customers owns a bunch of Cisco Catalys Switches and wants from us to review the configs. So he had sent me a lot of *.jar files.

I'm common with reading running-configs from Cisco devices and in years of reviewing i have only seen these config files als plain text.

Is there any possibility to extract the running config from that *.jar file? The files contain two merely two files, where my machine is saying these are executables.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you post these file somewhere or is it confidential? (**Dont do it if they contain passwords**). I have never seen `jar`s for configs either!? Are you sure that you dont need to use the jars to get the config (ie run them, they connect on the devices and pull out config...)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

These .jar files are probably configuration backups made with [Cisco Network Assistant](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/cloud-systems-management/network-assistant/index.html). These files are compressed (zipped) with a java extention, but you can extract them with WinZip or WinRAR or any other decompression software of choice.

Comment: the fact they are seen as executable is probably due to the fact that .jar is an extension for JAVA files that are executable.

Comment: RobinG has a good point here. Try decompressing .jar files with any unzip tool and check what's inside.